# Spawning a BoxCollider2D between to Vector3s

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am working on a game where a user will draw a line (got that part working) by using `input.touch`. What I want to have happen is have a `BoxCollider2D` to spawn in the center of the line segment at the correct rotation to match up with the line.

I think I can figure out how to spawn it in the center of the line segment but what I don't understand is spawning it at the correct rotation.

Here is the test script I am using to work out core functionality:

```
#pragma strict
var lastDotPosition : Vector3;
var lastPointExists : boolean = false;

var c1 : Color = Color.yellow;
var c2 : Color = Color.red;
var lengthOfLineRenderer : int = 2;

function Start() {
     var lineRenderer : LineRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent.<LineRenderer>();
     lineRenderer.material = new Material (Shader.Find("Particles/Additive"));
     lineRenderer.SetColors(c1, c2);
     lineRenderer.SetWidth(0.01,0.01);
     lineRenderer.SetVertexCount(lengthOfLineRenderer);
}

function Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        var lineRenderer : GameObject = new GameObject("Line");
        lineRenderer.AddComponent.<LineRenderer>();
        var newLine : LineRenderer = lineRenderer.GetComponent.<LineRenderer>();
        newLine.SetColors(c1, c2);
        newLine.SetWidth(0.1,0.1);
        newLine.SetVertexCount(lengthOfLineRenderer);

        var mouse : Vector2 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        var mouseRay : Ray2D = new Ray2D(mouse, Vector2.zero);
        var newDotPosition : Vector2 = mouseRay.origin;

        lineRenderer.AddComponent.<BoxCollider2D>();
        var newCol : BoxCollider2D = lineRenderer.GetComponent.<BoxCollider2D>();

        if (newDotPosition != lastDotPosition)
        {
            var pos : Vector3 = Vector3(lastDotPosition.x,lastDotPosition.y, 0);
            newLine.SetPosition(0, pos);
            var pos2 : Vector3 = Vector3(newDotPosition.x, newDotPosition.y, 0);
            newLine.SetPosition(1, pos2);
            newCol.size = Vector2(1, .1);
            var colAngle : float = Vector3.Dot(pos,pos2);
            colAngle = colAngle/(pos.magnitude*pos2.magnitude);
            colAngle = Mathf.Acos(colAngle);
            colAngle = colAngle*180/Mathf.PI;
            Debug.Log("Col angle: " + colAngle);
            lineRenderer.transform.Rotate(Vector3(0, 0, colAngle+17.28));
            Debug.Log("Rotation: " + lineRenderer.transform.rotation.z);
            lastDotPosition = newDotPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

---

I figured out how to calculate the angle between the two vectors that represent the endpoints of the line segment; `pos` (point start) and `pos2` (point end). What I don't get is getting the gameobject/collider to rotate to that degree. The angle between the two vectors is the var `colAngle`. Please tell me if I am calculating the angle correctly. If yes then how am I supposed to make the `BoxCollider2D` rotate to the correct rotation?

To test it just attach this script to an new empty gameobject and run it.